# Multiple Query with buttons in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am currently writing an app that I have a SQLite DB that contains data on a Tradable Collection Card Game. Each card has a Name, Power rating, Card Set, Color, and other info. What I am trying to find out is how to write a query statement to say someone wants to search for a card called Moses, they can type the name in and get the result of all the different Moses cards in the database, but say they want to narrow it down, and they know Moses was a White card, they can then type in Moses, then click on a button called White, then submit, this then queries the DB for the Moses card that in the color column is the word White and then displays the result. Now a step further, what if they wanted to find all the cards in say Color White and Blue from the Kings set, I would like to be able to click and select the White and Blue Button plus the button that says Kings, then hit submit, this then returns the results for all cards in the Kings Set that are White and Blue and displays the results in a new window that they can click on the name and it will brign up another window with all the info on that card?

I know it is a lot of info, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write some methods in your dbhelper:

```
public Cursor fetchSearch(String find) {
    String query = "SELECT name, power, set, color FROM cards WHERE name = '" + find + "%'";
    return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}

public Cursor fetchSearchColor(String find, String color) {
    String query = "SELECT name, power, set, color FROM cards WHERE name = '" + find + "%' AND color = '" + color + "'";
    return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

You would call fetchSearch for the plain search, and fetchSearchColor for the search for a specific color.  From here you can probably work out how to do multiple color searches.